# How to distinguish between a reference to a function with no paramters and a call to that function in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

Suppose I have a function definition like

```
def twice(f: Int => Unit): Unit = {
    f(1)
    f(1)
}

def oneParam(i: Int) = println(1)


twice(oneParam)
```

I can pass around oneParam by name, but if I do the same with a no parameter function:

```
def twice(f: Unit => Unit): Unit = {
    f()
    f()
}

def noParams() = println(2)

twice(noParams)
```

I get a compiler error because even though I declared noParams with an empty paramter list the compiler thinks I'm trying to call the function with no parameter list. How can I pass around this function then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is declared wrong. `Unit => Unit` is *not* a function, that takes no params, it's a function that takes one parameter of type `Unit`.

Try declaring it like this instead: `def twice(f: () => Unit)`

Comment: Ah. Looks like I was making some dodgy assumptions about how Unit works.

Comment: Is it the case then, that when mentioning the name of a function that takes an empty parmeter list, or no parameter list the compiler just looks at the types to decide whether or not to invoke the function?

Comment: Yes, it will treat a reference to a function as a function whereever a function is required. Sometimes it is ambiguous though. `println(noParams)` for example, prints out `()`. In cases like that, you can force it to be treated as a function with an underscore: `println(noParams _)`

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
 scala> def twice(f: () => Unit): Unit = {
 |   f()
 |   f()
 | }
 twice: (f: () => Unit)Unit


scala> def noParams() = println(2)
noParams: ()Unit

scala> twice(noParams)
2
2
```